# mysql cannot join tables even though field values are the same ( MySQL Workbench )

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables that i would like to join. They were loaded from separate files sources. I am trying to join then using this code.

```
SELECT mutation_icgc2016.idsample, mutation_icgc2016.primarySite, 
mutation_icgc2016.cancer, mutation_icgc2016.geneAffected, 
ICGCDiffSamplesJan2016.idsample
FROM mutation_icgc2016
  JOIN  ICGCDiffSamplesJan2016
  ON mutation_icgc2016.idsample=ICGCDiffSamplesJan2016.idsample
WHERE mutation_icgc2016.geneAffected is not null;
```

There is a problem however. The resulting table is empty. If i use just one value from the rows e.g.:

```
select * from ICGCOldSamplesJan2016 where idsample = "xxxxxx";
```

Results actually come up.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Then the values aren't the same. If `idsample` is not a numeric type, perhaps try `ON trim(mutation_icgc2016.idsample)=trim(ICGCDiffSamplesJan2016.idsample)`

Comment: precisely they must not be, when the results are presented in MySQL workbench its identical. I even copied it into excel to see if there was some space or something

Comment: Are they the same data type? Is there anything fishy going on here that we don't know about? Are both values definitely represented in both tables? Did you unplug it, wait 30 seconds, and then plug it back in? OK... maybe that last one is not such a great idea.

Comment: They are the same datatype (varchar) but different sizes one is 40 the other is 15. i.e. varchar(40) and varchar(15). Could that be the issue?

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem, unless data is being truncated to fit into that varchar(15) field. Is one of the fields UTF8 or some sort of unicode encoding and the other ascii/latin? I wonder if they aren't matching because of something like that. Grasping for straws though as it shouldn't make a difference (I don't think).

Comment: The only other thing that i did ifferent was when i loaded the mutation_icgc2016 table is that i had { fields optionally enclosed by '"'} the other table ICGCDiffSamplesJan2016 didnt use that because it was just one column of items. I used the optionally enclosed because of HeidiSQL which was showing it up with quotation marks around them.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution, I exported the files from excel becasue that is how they were given to me. Turns out Excel adds hidden/ special characters that mysql uses in identifying the fields. This is why trim doesnt work.

The solution was the to copy the row from excel into a text editor like notepad++ which i used in this case and saving the file as a csv. It worked! Thanks a lot for your help @JNevill.